# TCL regsub uses RegEx match as index in associate array

Tags: tcl, regsub

I'd like to automatically convert URLs, i.e

- "https://sc-uat.ct.example.com/sc/" into "https://invbeta.example.com/sc/"
- "https://sc-dev.ct.example.com/sc/" into "https://invtest.example.com/sc/"
- "https://sc-qa.ct.example.com/sc/" into "https://invdemo.example.com/sc/"

I've tried following code snippet in TCL

```
set loc "https://sc-uat.ct.example.com/sc/"

set envs(dev) "test"
set envs(uat) "beta"
set envs(qa) "demo"

puts $envs(uat)
regsub -nocase {://.+-(.+).ct.example.com} $loc {://inv[$envs(\1)].example.com} hostname

puts "new location = $hostname"
```

But the result is: new location = **https://inv[$envs(uat)].example.com/sc/**

It seems that *[$envs(uat)]* is **NOT** evaluated and substituted further with the real value. Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe use `string map` for this? If the set of website names to be converted isn't too huge...

Answer (score 1):

> But the result is: new location =
>   https://inv[$envs(uat)].example.com/sc/ It seems that [$envs(uat)] is eval-ed further.

You meant to say: `[$envs(uat)]` is *not* evaluated further?

This is because due to the curly braces in `{://inv[$envs(\1)].example.com}`, the drop-in string is taken literally, and not subjected to variable or command substitution. Besides, you don't want command and variable substitution (`[$envs(\1)]`), just one of them: `$envs(\1)` or `[set envs(\1)]`.

To overcome this, you must treat the regsub-processed string further via `subst`:

```
set hostname [subst -nocommands -nobackslashes [regsub -nocase {://.+-(.+).ct.example.com} $loc {://inv$envs(\1).example.com}]]
```

### Suggestions for improvement

I advise to avoid the use of `subst` in this context, because even when restricted, you might run into conflicts with characters special to Tcl in your hostnames (e.g., brackets in the IPv6 authority parts). Either you have to sanitize the `loc` string before, or, better work on string ranges like so:

```
if {[regexp -indices {://(.+-(.+)).ct.example.com} $loc _ replaceRange keyRange]} {
    set key [string range $loc {*}$keyRange]
    set sub [string cat "inv" $envs($key)]
    set hostname [string replace $loc {*}$replaceRange $sub]
}
```